# Unable to empty the dynamically created textbox value when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('change', ".checkboxtd", function() {
    var inden_id = $(this).parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().children().val();
    alert(inden_id);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {

        alert('Un checked');
        $('#indent_detailid').val('');
        //$('#indent_detailid').val('');
    }
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
$('.recptdt').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"   class = "checkboxtd" name = "check[]" style="margin-left:15%" value="O"></td><td>' + i + '</td><td>' + b.item_type + '</td><td>' + b.item_name + '</td><td>' + b.model_no + '</td><td class = "serialno" >' + b.serial_no + '</td><td>' + b.unit + '</td><td style = "display:none"><input class = "form-control" type = "text"  name = "" readonly id = "issuqantity"></td><td style = "display:none ">' + b.receipt_qty + '</td><td style = "display:none"><input class = "form-control" type = "text" value = ' + b.indent_issue_id + ' name = "issu_id[]" id = "issu_id"></td><td style = "display:none"><input type = "text" id = "stock_idno" name = "stock_idno[]" value ="' + b.det_stock_id + '"><td style = "display:"><input class = "form-control" type = "text" value = ' + b.indent_detail_id2 + ' name = "indent_detailid2[]" id = "indent_detailid"></td><td style = ""><input class = "form-control issuqantity" type = "text" value = ' + b.issue_qty + ' name = "issuqantity[]"   readonly = "readonly"  id = "issuqantity"></td><td><input type = "text" value = ""  name = "recqty[]" class = "form-control booksqty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"  id = "req_val"/></td><td style = "display:"><input type = "text" name = "det1_indent_detail_id1[]" value = "' + b.indent_detail_id1 + '"></td><td><input type = "text" value = "' + b.item_id + '" class = "itm_id" name = "itm_id[]"/></td></tr>');
```

how to empty the `$('#indent_detailid').val('');` alert working properly .Still unable to empty the dynamically created textbox value...!!

Comment: pls provide html of your dynamic textbox with checkbox

Comment: can you add dynamically created textbox code.

Comment: _dynamically created textbox value_ where is it? How do you append it in the dom?

Comment: `var inden_id = $(this).parent().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().next().children().val();` I would assume this could be written way more easily

Comment: Thanks for replay. updated html code.

Comment: @empiric Yeah...it can be

Comment: @satish may be you are duplicating same id again and again.

Comment: @jai..need to remove that duplicate

Comment: Finally..catched a cat after digging a hill:)

Answer (score 0):

you r repeating id so add i value to id
like

```
<input class = "form-control" type = "text" value = ' + b.indent_detail_id2 + ' name = "indent_detailid2[]" id = "indent_detailid"+i>
```

get and reset like

```
var i = $(this).parent().next().val();
 $('#indent_detailid'+ i).val('');
```